# All lowest common ancestor with NetworkX

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, lowest-common-ancestor

I want to get all LCA nodes from node"a" and node"o".

In this DiGraph, node"l" and node"m" are LCA nodes.

The following is the code.

```
import networkx as nx

def calc_length(Graph, node1, node2, elem):
    length1 = nx.shortest_path_length(Graph, node1, elem)
    length2 = nx.shortest_path_length(Graph, node1, elem)
    length_sum = length1 + length2
    return length_sum

G = nx.DiGraph() #Directed graph
G.add_nodes_from(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p"])
edges = [("a","b"),("b","c"),("b","d"),("a","e"),("a","h"),("e","f"),("e","g"),("e","i"),("h","l"),("h","m"),("g","j"),("o","p"),("o","n"),("n","m"),("n","l"),("n","k"),("p","j"),]
G.add_edges_from([(e[0], e[1]) for e in edges])

preds_1 = nx.bfs_predecessors(G, "a")
preds_2 = nx.bfs_predecessors(G, "o")
common_preds = set([n for n in preds_1]).intersection(set([n for n in preds_2]))
common_preds = list(common_preds)
dic ={}
for elem in common_preds:
    length_sum = calc_length(G, "a", "o", elem)
    dic[elem] = length_sum

min_num = min(dic.values())
for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]):
    if v != min_num:
        break
    else:
        print k, v
```

I want faster execution speed.

Please let me know if you have a better method to solve the problem than the one previously mentioned.

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me. `preds_1` and `preds_2` are empty as 'a' and 'o' have no predecessors....

Comment: Presumably `length_2` should depend on `node_2`, not `node_1`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was mistaken. length_2 depends on node2.

Comment: Did the answer work for you, @kh_si0567? If so, could you maybe accept it to mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here, some of which I have pointed out in the comments. Part of the problem is that the nomenclature is confusing: the lowest common ancestor ([as defined on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) and presumably in computer science in general) really should be named lowest common descendant in order to conform with the nomenclature used by networkx (and any sane network scientist that I know of). Your breadth-first-search should hence really follow the descendants, not the predecessors. The following implements such an LCA search:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()
import networkx as nx

def find_lowest_common_ancestor(graph, a, b):
    """
    Find the lowest common ancestor in the directed, acyclic graph of node a and b.
    The LCA is defined as on

    @reference:
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor

    Notes:
    ------
    This definition is the opposite of the term as it is used e.g. in biology!

    Arguments:
    ----------
        graph: networkx.DiGraph instance
            directed, acyclic, graph

        a, b:
            node IDs

    Returns:
    --------
        lca: [node 1, ..., node n]
            list of lowest common ancestor nodes (can be more than one)
    """

    assert nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(graph), "Graph has to be acyclic and directed."

    # get ancestors of both (intersection)
    common_ancestors = list(nx.descendants(graph, a) & nx.descendants(graph, b))

    # get sum of path lengths
    sum_of_path_lengths = np.zeros((len(common_ancestors)))
    for ii, c in enumerate(common_ancestors):
        sum_of_path_lengths[ii] = nx.shortest_path_length(graph, a, c) \
                                  + nx.shortest_path_length(graph, b, c)

    # print common_ancestors
    # print sum_of_path_lengths

    # return minima
    minima, = np.where(sum_of_path_lengths == np.min(sum_of_path_lengths))

    return [common_ancestors[ii] for ii in minima]

def test():

    nodes = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p"]
    edges = [("a","b"),
             ("b","c"),
             ("b","d"),
             ("a","e"),
             ("a","h"),
             ("e","f"),
             ("e","g"),
             ("e","i"),
             ("h","l"),
             ("h","m"),
             ("g","j"),
             ("o","p"),
             ("o","n"),
             ("n","m"),
             ("n","l"),
             ("n","k"),
             ("p","j"),]

    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    G.add_edges_from(edges)

    # plot
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels=dict([(c, c) for c in 'abcdefghijklmnop']))
    plt.show()

    a,b = 'a','o'
    lca = find_lowest_common_ancestor(G, a, b)
    print "Lowest common ancestor(s) for {} and {}: {}".format(a, b, lca)

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```